# WooCommerce checkout select field: Insert a key/value before calculated options array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on my WordPress / Woocommerce website.
How can I add a constant value, which would always be the first value in the drop down list which consists of times (hour:minute). This constant value at the top should say "As soon as possible".

Here is the code which generates the form itself:

```
public function time_select( $checkout ) { 
    echo '<div id="local-pickup-time-select"><h2>' . __( 'Delivery Time', $this->plugin_slug ) . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'local_pickup_time_select', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'local-pickup-time-select-field form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery Time', $this->plugin_slug ),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => self::create_hour_options()
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'local_pickup_time_select' ));

    self::create_hour_options();

    echo '</div>';
}

public function pickup_time_select_translatable( $value ) {
    $value = preg_replace('/(\d)_(\d)/','$1:$2', $value);
    $value = explode('_', $value);
    $return = __( $value[0], $this->plugin_slug ). ' ' .$value[1];
    return $return;
}

public function create_hour_options() {
    // Make sure we have a time zone set
    $offset = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
    $timezone_setting = get_option( 'timezone_string' );

    if ( $timezone_setting ) {
        date_default_timezone_set( get_option( 'timezone_string', 'America/New_York' ) );
    }
    else {
        $timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr( null, $offset * 3600, true );
        if( $timezone === false ) $timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr( null, $offset * 3600, false );
        date_default_timezone_set( $timezone );
    }

    // Get days closed textarea from settings, explode into an array
    $closing_days_raw = trim( get_option( 'local_pickup_hours_closings' ) );
    $closing_days = explode( "\n", $closing_days_raw );
    $closing_days = array_filter( $closing_days, 'trim' );

    // Get delay, interval, and number of days ahead settings
    $delay_minutes = get_option( 'local_pickup_delay_minutes', 60 );
    $interval = get_option( 'local_pickup_hours_interval', 30 );
    $num_days_allowed = get_option( 'local_pickup_days_ahead', 1 );

    // Setup time variables for calculations
    $today_name = strtolower( date( 'l' ) );
    $today_date = date( 'm/d/Y' );

    // Create an empty array for our dates
    $pickup_options = array();

    //Translateble days
    __( 'Monday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Tuesday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Wednesday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Thursday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Friday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Saturday', $this->plugin_slug );
    __( 'Sunday', $this->plugin_slug );

    // Add empty option
    $pickup_options[''] = __( 'Select time', $this->plugin_slug );

    // Loop through all days ahead and add the pickup time options to the array
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_days_allowed; $i++ ) {

        // Get the date of current iteration
        $current_day_name = date( 'l', strtotime( "+$i days" ) );
        $current_day_name_lower = strtolower( $current_day_name );

        // Get the day's opening and closing times
        $open_time = get_option( 'local_pickup_hours_' . $current_day_name_lower . '_start', '10:00' );
        $close_time = get_option( 'local_pickup_hours_' . $current_day_name_lower . '_end', '19:00' );

        // Today
        $tStart = strtotime( $open_time );
        $tEnd = strtotime( $close_time );
        $tNow = $tStart;
        $current_time = time();

        // Date format based on user settings
        $date_format = get_option('time_format');
        $date_format_key = preg_replace("/[^\w]+/", "_", $date_format);

        // If Closed today or today's pickup times are over, don't allow a pickup option
        if ( ( in_array( $today_date, $closing_days ) || ( $current_time >= $tEnd ) )  && $num_days_allowed == 1 ) {

            // Set drop down text to let user know store is closed
            $pickup_options['closed_today'] = __( 'Closed today, please check back tomorrow!', $this->plugin_slug );

            // Hide Order Review so user doesn't order anything today
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );

        }
        else {
            // Create array of time options to return to woocommerce_form_field

            // Today
            if ( $i == 0) {

                // Check if it's not too late for pickup
                if ( $current_time < $tEnd ) {

                    // Fix tNow if is pickup possible today
                    if ( $i == 0 ) {
                        $todayStart = $tStart;
                        $delayStart = strtotime("+$delay_minutes minutes", $current_time);
                        while ( $todayStart <= $delayStart ) {
                            $todayStart = strtotime("+$interval minutes", $todayStart);
                        }
                        $tNow = $todayStart;
                    }

                    while ( $tNow <= $tEnd ) {

                        $day_name = __( 'Today', $this->plugin_slug );

                        $option_key = $current_day_name . date( $date_format_key, $tNow );
                        $option_value = $day_name . ' ' . date( $date_format, $tNow );

                        $pickup_options[$option_key] = $option_value;

                        $tNow = strtotime( "+$interval minutes", $tNow );
                    }

                }

            // Other days
            } else {

                if ( !empty($open_time) && !empty($close_time )) {
                    while ( $tNow <= $tEnd ) {

                        $day_name = __( $current_day_name, $this->plugin_slug );

                        $option_key = $current_day_name . date( $date_format_key, $tNow );
                        $option_value = $day_name . ' ' . date( $date_format, $tNow );

                        $pickup_options[$option_key] = $option_value;

                        $tNow = strtotime( "+$interval minutes", $tNow );

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    } // end for loop

    if ( count($pickup_options) == 1) {
        // Set drop down text to let user know store is closed
        $pickup_options['closed_today'] = __( 'Closed today, please check back tomorrow!', $this->plugin_slug );

        // Hide Order Review so user doesn't order anything today
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
    }

    return $pickup_options;
}
```

The final result would look something like this **Drop-down list**:

> - As soon as possible
> - Tuesday 7:30 pm
> - Tuesday 8:00 pm
> - Tuesday 8:30 pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways to do it depending if the key value you want for "As soon as possible" choice has to be dynamic. This is done in your first function with `array_merge()` this way:

```
public function time_select( $checkout ) { 
    echo '<div id="local-pickup-time-select"><h2>' . __( 'Delivery Time', $this->plugin_slug ) . '</h2>';

    // The default empty value and your translatable sentence to be included
    $array_to_insert = array( 
        ''        => __( 'Select your delivery time', $this->plugin_slug ),
        'as_soon' => __( 'As soon as possible', $this->plugin_slug ) 
    );

    // Getting your calculated hours options array
    $options = self::create_hour_options();

    // Merging both arrays in one
    $options = array_merge( $array_to_insert, $options );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'local_pickup_time_select', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'local-pickup-time-select-field form-row-wide' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery Time', $this->plugin_slug ),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => $options,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'local_pickup_time_select' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. you will get that:

[image]

> I have noticed in your code that your `//Translateble days` (monday to sunday) are not set in individual variables or in an array…